# SSH Permission denied (publickey,password) - container docker ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ssh

I've installed Docker on my windows 10 and I'm using my WSL1 in order to create dockerfile, build and run containers and I cannot connect via ssh, I get  **Permission denied (publickey,password)**

**My dockerfile is**:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

**My docker ps is :**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                   NAMES
b41411ef7a8a   eg_sshd   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:32768->22/tcp   test_sshd
```

The ssh port is this :

```
➜ root$ docker port test_sshd 22
0.0.0.0:32768
```

**When I'm trying to connet via ssh I get** **"Permission denied"**

```
➜  root$ ssh root@0.0.0.0 -p 32768                  
root@0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

**The ssh service is up**

```
➜ root$ docker exec b41411ef7a8a service ssh status
 * sshd is running
```

What I'm doing wrong...I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

because the original line is:

```
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

So `sed` works but the option remains commented-out. No doubt you know what to do to fix this but just in case the solution is to add `#` to the matching part:

```
RUN sed -Ei 's/#(PermitRootLogin).+/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

By the way, usually you do not need a `ssh` server in a container to get inside it. It is possible to open a shell inside a container with `docker exec -it <container> sh` or (for Kubernetes) `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> sh`.